# Fluid simulation is choppy with animated obstacle descending on Z axis [video included]

Tags: fluid-simulation

see video for example [HERE](https://youtu.be/Wy8dxTn8roE).

I have a cylinder that's an obstacle for my fluid simulation. It descends, and the fluid is supposed to descend with it. Well... it does, but on the bottom where the fluid meets the obstacle, it jumps instead of gradually going with the obstacle. Here's the blend file for review: [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3msicxt1ucyu9bw/Fluid%20test.blend?dl=0).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is due to the resolution of the domain object. Try with a higher resolution, it should descends more smoothly (shorter steps). The trick is to find the acceptable maximal resolution ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error; that's simply Blender telling you that your fluid it too low res. Generally, I would say, "up the *Final Resolution:* for a smoother result," but that won't help that much in your case (150 should be plenty for most anything).

However, in this case, the issue is that your *Domain* is **HUGE!!!** The *Domain* should be exactly that; a cube that encompasses anywhere your fluid might travel and **NOTHING ELSE!** So if you scale your domain cube from **Img 1** (where it currently is) to **Img 2** (what I am suggesting), your resolution (being relative to the size of the *Domain*) will "increase."

*Img 1; how you have it:*

[image]

*Img 2; what I'm recommending:*

[image]

Notice how it only encompasses where the water will be. Lastly, consider the following image, which shows how your fluid will bake after the modification (so much more concentration!).

*I only let it bake the first frame, because baking will now take longer:*

[image]

Here is a .blend file with the modifications:

[image]

Comment: Shady Puck, appreciate the reply and feedback. I'll definitely have to consider the domain size more carefully in the future! However, if you baked the simulation to around 11% with your modified .blend file, you'd see that it's still doing the same thing: when the cylinder gradually lowers, the fluid jumps down to meet it every couple of frames in a very non-fluid movement. I can't say this solution fixed the problem.

Comment: @Jesse Trying to bake now. That's very interesting. I will look at that.

Comment: I'm with you, I'm as equally curious about its behavior as I am solving it.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Jesse I believe that you would have to enhance the resolution to infinity before it was completely smooth. The same way Blender uses many_n_-gons instead of circles, it uses smaller and smaller cubes instead of fluid. I can think of two solutions. 1.) Up the res and move the camera farther away so you don't notice. 2.) Let it bake and then keyframe the _Domain's Location_ on the Z-axis so the water glides w/ the cylinder. I'm sorry, but there is no perfect solution to this problem in this Blender version. By the way, if my answer or this comment helped, please consider accepting it.